# OrientDB - Duplicate a record into a read-only class

Tags: hook, orientdb

**When a user creates a record, this record needs to be duplicated into a read-only class.**

Two vertex classes, one with full access for user, the second with read-only access. Whenever a record is created in the full access class a duplicate record needs to be created within the read-only class.

A dynamic hook almost works, but the function will not fire because the user lacks the create privilege on the readOnly class. How can I create a duplicate record?

```
//from console
CREATE CLASS allRights EXTENDS V, OTriggered;
CREATE CLASS readOnly EXTENDS V;
ALTER CLASS allRights CUSTOM onAfterCreate=createDuplicate

CREATE FUNCTION createDuplicate "db.command(\"CREATE VERTEX readOnly set someField = \\\"\" + doc.field(\'someField\')+\"\\\"\");" LANGUAGE Javascript

INSERT INTO ORole SET name = 'testUser', mode = 0;
UPDATE ORole PUT rules = "database.class.readOnly", 2 WHERE name = "testUser";
UPDATE ORole PUT rules = "database.class.allRights", 15 WHERE name = "testUser"
UPDATE ORole PUT rules = "database.class.*", 15 WHERE name = "testUser"


INSERT INTO OUser SET name = 'testUser', password = 'password', status = 'ACTIVE', roles = (SELECT FROM ORole WHERE name = 'testUser')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 solutions for this problem:

1. You could allow to the user the permission to READ and CREATE
   record, but not to UPDATE and DELETE them. In this way the hook
   would work.
2. In the JS function you could switch to a user with the privilege to create the record. This is the code in JS: `db.switchUser('superuser', 'superuser')`

Comment: The second solution would solve my problem. If I knew how to pass the credentials. I've looked through the documentation and I cannot figure this out. Please advise.

Comment: in JS you can do: `db.switchUser('superuser', 'superuser')`. So you can have a 'superuser' with the right privileges.

Comment: Hi Lvca, I have been trying to get this to work, I cannot get the syntax correct. Is it possible to get some more information on how to make this work? Just adding the db.switchUser method above the db.command returns this error " com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Database 'plocal:/home/champion/orientdb/databases/test' is closed ". I have tried other combinations, but I am not getting any closer and I cannot find a solution in the documentation. How to get it working?

Comment: Try creating a function with just this content and execute it: `db.switchUser("admin", "admin"); return db.query("select from OUSer");`

Comment: Lvca you are the best. It was my error in not getting it to work right away. Solution works as described.

Comment: Cool, glad to help ;-)